# playing MPEG-dash streaming with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

I'm having a problem when playing MPEG-dash streaming with ffmpeg. I know there are a lot of tools can play MPEG-dash like OSMO4, DASH.js.. However, I am wondering if I can play MPEG-dash with FFMPEG? 
And one more question, How can I determine startup time when playing MPEG-dash streaming? It means, the duration time when I request a MPD file from a server until I get the first picture of video display on a screen? 
Thanks!

Comment: You can use `ffmpeg -formats` and `ffmpeg -codecs` to check for compatibility

Answer (score 8):

ffmpeg can now (tickets:[5269](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5269),[7382](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7382) were fixed) play MPEG DASH but you need to make sure that support is enabled in the binary (which appears to be uncommon as DASH demuxing support doesn't seem to be normally enabled by default). As mentioned in the comments by @aergistal you can check for dash demuxing support (you will also need appropriate codec support according to the DASH MPD but most of the usual ones are usually enabled):

```
ffmpeg -formats | grep dash
```

It should show (`D` indicates support for Demuxing and `E` for muxing):

```
DE dash            DASH Muxer
```

If you don't see DASH Demuxing support then you'll need to (re)compile ffmpeg. [Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) the sources, unpack and enter the src code directory, then enable dash demuxing support using configure (you'll also need to install `libxml2` support if you don't have it):

```
ffmpeg-X.X.X$ ./configure --enable-demuxer=dash --enable-libxml2
ffmpeg-X.X.X$ make
```

Once supported is enabled you should be able to play a test stream like this:

```
ffplay  http://dash.edgesuite.net/dash264/TestCases/1a/netflix/exMPD_BIP_TC1.mpd
```

To answer your second question - the startup delay is determined by the time taken to download the MPD and then perform the actions in the MPD - typically it needs to download the initialisation segment and then get the first media segment before playback can begin.

Comment: Built with those options on (4.2.3). However, when playing mpd from facebook video, ffmpeg always returns "HTTP error 403 Forbidden". On the contrary, VLC can play the same mpd url without any issue. Any idea?