# How to play mpeg-dash audio streams from console?

Tags: streaming, vlc, mpeg-dash, mpv

Is there a way to play an [mpeg-dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP) audio stream from console? This is an example [stream](https://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/dash/nonuk/dash_low/aks/bbc_world_service.mpd).

It would also be good to be able to force a specific stream quality.

I have tried `mpv`, `cvlc` but they don't seem to be able to parse the playlist and assemble the chunks.

Comment: Some useful info here - may save you some time of you have not seen it already. Choosing a specific stream seems to be a common issue: http://ronallo.com/blog/testing-dash-and-hls-streams-on-linux/

Comment: Take a look at this related question/answer using `ffmpeg` to playback DASH: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52853088/436794

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment one can now use ffmpeg's `ffplay` utility to playback DASH content from the command line. In earlier versions of ffmpeg DASH playback wasn't always enabled - see my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52853088/436794) for details e.g.:

```
ffplay  http://dash.edgesuite.net/dash264/TestCases/1a/netflix/exMPD_BIP_TC1.mpd
```

One can also use `ffmpeg` to process DASH media - so you can easily use it to download (or transform) DASH content e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -i http://dash.edgesuite.net/dash264/TestCases/1a/netflix/exMPD_BIP_TC1.mpd exMPD_BIP_TC1.mp4
```

Comment: also needed to add `-nodisp` in order to suppress the gui window

Answer (score 0):

## *Update:* `VLC` support for dash streaming

Latest versions of VLC are able to handle dash streams, so the terminal invocation would be:

```
cvlc https://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/dash/nonuk/dash_low/aks/bbc_world_service.mpd
```

#### Osmo4 (gpac)

[`osmo4`](https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/) which is part of the [`gpac`](https://github.com/gpac/gpac) project can play dash MPD files, but unfortunately, it does not work in headless mode for audio-only streams.

#### dash.js

This is the official [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js) library which requires a browser. Whether it can be made to work under nodejs is not clear.

Here is a minimal implementation for playing an audio/video dash stream adapted from the [dash.js readme](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dash.js</title>
    <style>
        video {
            width: 640px;
            height: 360px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<video id="videoPlayer" data-dashjs-player autoplay controls src="https://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/dash/nonuk/dash_low/aks/bbc_world_service.mpd">
</video>

<script src="//cdn.dashjs.org/latest/dash.all.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Note: The file above will NOT work when opened from the local file system over a `file:///` protocol. It requires a web server; any of the oneliners listed [here](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255) would do.

#### Using Chrome/Chromium Headless

As of version 59 Google Chrome/Chromium can run in headless mode, which means it can be used on a headless system. Since there is no 'official' text-mode client for dash.js a somewhat heavyweight way to play dash audio in terminal would be opening it with headless chrome/chromium:

```bash
chromium-browser --headless --disable-gpu --repl https://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/dash/nonuk/dash_low/aks/bbc_world_service.mpd
```

Occasionally chrome/chromium would fail playing on first invocation, the `--repl` option seems to allow it to eventually start playing. The repl also lets you type arbitrary javascript like e.g. `document.location.reload()`.